# Delaying The Opening Of 2 Popups

Tags: javascript

I have 2 Popups and I need that them not opening together.
So, I want for apply a simple delay.

This is the code of a popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pmauid = 'Numbers';
var pmawid = 'Numbers';
var fq = '0';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mypopnetwork.com"></script>
```

How I can apply a delay in this javascript code using this function:

```
function delay(ms) {
    var start = +new Date;
    while ((+new Date - start) < ms);
}

// start image loading (I assume you need this for tracking?)
delay(150);
```

Maybe in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout()
var pmauid = 'Numbers';
var pmawid = 'Numbers';
var fq = '0';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mypopnetwork.com"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery?There is no delay function in javascript.You can use setTimeout otherwise please add jquery tag.

Comment: You don't wan't to use that delay function. It will lock up the browser during the delay. Use a asynchronous delay instead with window.setTimeout.

Comment: I have edited added window.setTimeout. It's correct?

Comment: Yep. Look for setTimeout!

Answer (score 0):

The closest function in javascript that you can find is [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). In second parameter you specify number of milliseconds when function has to be called, and in first parameter you are passing function callback that will be called after number of milliseconds expire.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // your code
}, 150);
```

JavaScript is single threaded and it uses async calls to processes multiple tasks. Your example will block main thread for 150ms and UI will not be responsive, that is why you should use setTimeout, which is not blocking main thread.

Comment: yes, after 150ms whatever code inside of the function will be executed, without blocking main thread. You can test it by entering any alert() function. For instance enter alert('Hello World'); instead of "// your code"

Comment: I tried, not works. I see only the text "setTimeout(function() { }, 150); " in my page. Without the javascript code.

Comment: Could you please provide code example at https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can help you.

Comment: I can't share popup code because count like poor traffic after. I tried also with window.setTimeout():

<script type="text/javascript" window.setTimeout() src="http://mypopnetwork.com"></script>   But I think the syntax is wrong.